# How Can I Use Image from Resource in skcanvas.drawImage?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am trying to use the SkiaSharp SKDocument class to write a PDF in xamarin, but I I'm having trouble to use an image from "MyProject.Droid/Resources/Drawable" in skCanvas.drawImage(). I stored the image in ImageSource, I need to convert it to SKImage, but how?

```
SKDocument sKDocument = 
SKDocument.CreatePdf("/storage/emulated/0/Teste5.pdf");
var canvas = sKDocument.BeginPage(2480, 3508);
canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);

Image image = new Image();
image.Source = "MyImage.png";
canvas.DrawImage();
```

I need to cast image to Skimage to be able to draw it

Comment: use SKImage.FromBitmap() or SKImage.FromEncodedData()

Comment: Thanks Jason by te answer, but both don`t accept xamarin.forms.image as parameters

Comment: I know that.  You have to create the SKImage from the resource using a stream or byte[], not the Forms Image.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/bitmaps

Comment: It works! You made my day Jason, thaks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

load the data as a `stream` or `byte[]` from resources, then use either `SKImage.FromBitmap()` or `SKImage.FromEncodedData()` to create the `SKImage`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/bitmaps

Comment: Your link is very useful <3